# React Router: Creating a single page for Json Data from Api

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have an application where it renders a list of users from an api and what I want to do is when the user clicks one of the list it leads to that users information page via React Router. What is the best way to implement this on React?

I was trying to solve it but none came up good.

The code is sensitive but here's the picture of what I've done so far: 
Index component:

- Route to index
- Route to other pages  Route to single page Users Page:
- Api Call
- Users Data Rendered with Link to their single Page

I can access the pages but cannot pass the data to be rendered

Comment: Can we see what you’ve tried so far?

Comment: I edited the question with the picture of what I was trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did is pass on that page another prop via Link component here is an example

```
<Link   style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} 
        to={ 
              {
                pathname:`${link}/${row.id}`,
                singleData: row
              } 
  }>
     {currentValue}
 </Link>
```

So I found out you can pass another custom prop by adding it as an object property in the 'to' Props. Should've read the documentation. If you have questions just answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `Link` from `react-router-dom` to notify your router the location is changed and then have Router evaluate it and determine it's View/Container it loads off that.

Here is a working sample:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

---

Here is some sample code on how you can use Router to get these details:

--- Sample use of Router and passing in it's props:

```
 <Route
    exact
    path="/user/view/:id"
    render={props => <CustomerView user={this.state.user} {...props} />
    }
  />

 // By spreading the props into the View you have access to the this.props.match.params.id
```

--- In your User Container

```
  fetchUser = () => {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id;
    postData("/documents/fetch-document", { id: id }).then(res => {
      this.setState({
        document: res,
        ...this.defaultState,
        isLoading: false
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the link but this is actually the basic of a website. What I wanted is render a data of users from an api and when they click their profile it leads to their singles page.

Comment: That's how you do that. Once you link them to their page, you have access to passing in props to the component from the Router ---- <Route
            exact
            path="/document/view/:id"
            render={props =>
              !this.isLoggedIn() ? (
                <Redirect to="/login" />
              ) : (
                <DocumentView user={this.state.user} {...props} />
              )
            }
          />    ---- In the DocumentView I can then get this.props.match.params.id and pass it to a post request to query with